# PHP Dynamically creating KML for multiple placemarks on map

Tags: php, kml

Currently struggling with PHP and creating KML from it. I'm using the last.fm API (geoGetevents) to grab events from 'location' (for  example, user searches for Manchester) and then (using KML - as I feel more comfortable with it than JS) plot these on a map.

I'm finding that I get invalid KML/KMZ errors when linking to a google map from my feed. Having said that, I know why.. Everything is contained in one file - including the KML that PHP generates.

So with GET variable, the URL is http://example.net/dmp/search.php?city=bristol

Google Maps is ignoring the rest of the URL after the '?' - is there any way I can send the dynamically generated KML to google maps? Maybe creating a separate KML file?

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"> <!-- Sets KML header --> 
<Folder> 
<name>Gigs</name> 
      <Placemark><name>As I Lay Dying</name><description> etc
```

That is the current KML that is created by the PHP.

Hope you can help, and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i have your answer have you put the link inside a Cdata inside your description
this will allow a bubble to appear above the click icon with html in it

good example is a marinetraffic.com

sending dynamically created kml.

add this to your Apache mime.types
application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml kml

at the top of the page that outputs the file put this
Header('Content-type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml');

yada yada

ps you can find out alot about the cdata at http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html

then you need to create a network link file its a kml file that tells google maps ware to look for your server

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
      <Folder>
        <name>Network Links</name>
        <visibility>0</visibility>
        <open>0</open>
        <description>Network link example 1</description>
        <NetworkLink>
          <name>Random Placemark</name>
          <visibility>0</visibility>
          <open>0</open>
          <description>A simple server-side script that generates a new random
            placemark on each call</description>
          <refreshVisibility>0</refreshVisibility>
          <flyToView>0</flyToView>
          <Link>
<refreshInterval>600.0</refreshInterval>

<refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode>
            <href>http://yourserver.com/cgi-bin/randomPlacemark.py</href>
          </Link>
        </NetworkLink>
      </Folder>
    </kml>
```

i added Refresh interval as this will make it auto update

hope this helps chap since you know a alot more php than i do would you mind having a look at my problem ! haha jope this helps

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at your problem, but I'm no PHP guru!

Answer (score 0):

your question was a bit fuzzy.  let us address how to create dynamic KML files for use with googlemaps simplest interface - the website.

[click here for example](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/kml/sundials.kml&hl=en&sll=-23.564617,-46.664729&sspn=0.010503,0.021136&t=m&z=2)

the first issue you must be aware of is that, so as to avoid using the website as a dynamic interface, google restricts how often it refreshes the KML (you might have changed it, but google cached it).  it will usually be more than 10 minutes before google refreshes its cache.

therefore, the best thing would be to change your KML name, the link to googlemaps embedding and refresh your embedded map.

note: you can write PHP code that spits out a KML and call the PHP file directly from within the googlemaps site.

Comment: ps: this is not a theoretical answer, this is how i successfully addresss this situation on my website's realtime person/asset tracker (which i am in the process of refactoring for OpenLayers and OpenStreetMaps).   Google is progressively restricting use of its api, making it financially unfeasible for me to use their technology on free apps/websites.

Comment: pps: as of jun2012, fly-to is working again, but LineString tracing is not working properly (the overlay is not completely drawn in most cases).  might be just a snafu in the new version of googlemaps api.  that, in and of itself, is a serious problem.  google is not interested in backward compatibility: not only does it change whole families of commands between API versions, it also changes its logic and structure.  i wasted 6 months of development because i trusted google to supply a stable and consistent platform.  i will not repeat this mistake.  OpenLayers is the way to go.