# How to read map tile images from database stored locally into google earth plugin using just javascript/html5?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, google-earth-plugin

I have an SQLite database with coordinates and tiled up map data/images that I can use to calculate corresponding **LatLonBox** elements for a **GroundOverlay** in a KMZ/KML for the Google Earth plugin. I can do the necessary query to determine what images go where on the plugin (aka I can create the **GroundOverlay** bounds correctly).

Problem:
This is just an example use case, I'm not actually planning on using an OSM map tile - Let's say I downloaded this image:
[OSM map tile http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/7/41/79.png](http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/7/41/79.png)

from -> http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/7/41/79.png

and put it into an sqlite database.

Let's say I then calculated the **LatLonBox** for that image and made a kml file via javascript:

```
var groundOverlay = ge.createGroundOverlay('');
groundOverlay.setIcon(ge.createIcon(''))
groundOverlay.getIcon().setHref("http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/7/41/79.png");
groundOverlay.setLatLonBox(ge.createLatLonBox(''));

var center = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
var north = -38.822591;
var south = -40.979898;
var east = -61.875;
var west = -64.6875;
var rotation = 0;
var latLonBox = groundOverlay.getLatLonBox();
latLonBox.setBox(north, south, east, west, rotation);

ge.getFeatures().appendChild(groundOverlay);
```

Example KML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <GroundOverlay>
    <name> 00</name>
    <Icon>
      <href>http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/7/41/79.png</href>
      <drawOrder>0</drawOrder>
    </Icon>
    <LatLonBox>
      <north>-38.822591</north>
      <south>-40.979898</south>
      <east>-61.875</east>
      <west>-64.6875</west>
      <rotation>0.0</rotation>
    </LatLonBox>
  </GroundOverlay>
</kml>
```

Except instead of the **href** element pointing to http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/7/41/79.png, I want it to point to the image in my database. It doesn't have to directly point to the image in the database, I can use javascript to get the specific image(s) of interest, but once I have the image data I am lost on what to do.

So I can access the sqlite database with the image of interest in it on my local filesystem via javascript/html5 and parse an almost complete KML file (missing the href element because I don't know how to get the correct href element).

Once I'm at this point, I don't know where to go. How would I display that image on the google earth plugin or is it even possible without hosting it on a server? Is it possible to use javascript to serve up those images (aka act like a server in the browser to link the images in the database to a specific href that can be referenced in a kml document)?

The third element from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14655086/1445252)   makes me think it MIGHT be possible, but since it wasn't tried and it was aimed at serving up a KML file rather than the href element inside the KML file, I have no idea if it even applies.

Can this be done solely with javascript or must the images be hosted somehow/somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"Can this be done solely with javascript or must the images be hosted..."
```

Yes, they must be hosted either locally or remotely, how can you possible serve them if they aren't?

The Kml `<href>` element must contain a link to a local or remote file that is accessible via HTTP or HTTPS.

```
"Is it possible to use javascript to serve up those images"
```

No, JavaScript is a client side language -it doesn't have access to the networking layer or local file system - it can't 'serve' anything.

You could always just set up a local server to do this, Windows comes with IIS built in for example.

It is fine to have the `<href>` element point to a local file via http, e.g. `http://localhost/whatever.kml`, `https://127.0.0.1/images/foo.jpg`, etc.